# How to initialize an empty array that can accept any size?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def __init__(self):
        self.b = []
        for i in range(2):
            board_num = input("Type something to test this out: ")
            n = int(input("enter n: "))
            if board_num == 2:
                self.b = ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B']
    #            n==4
            elif board_num == 3:
                self.b = ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B']
    #            n==6
            elif board_num == 4:
                self.b = ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R', 
                            'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B']
        numpy.arange(n*n).reshape((n,n))
        self.b=numpy.array(self.b)
        numpy.random.shuffle(self.b)
        self.b=self.b.reshape(n,n)

  line 30, in __init__
    self.b=self.b.reshape(n,n)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (2,2)
```

Comment: What are you entering for `n`? It looks like the array is empty by the time your reach `self.b = numpy.array(self.b)`.

Comment: n is the size of the array.

Comment: `def __init__(self):
        self.b = ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B']
        numpy.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
        self.b=numpy.array(self.b)
        numpy.random.shuffle(self.b)
        self.b=self.b.reshape(4,4)`       This is my code,  It is for one array only, I want to set a loop which can accept variable sized array.

Comment: Apologies - I mean for `board_num`. Could you update your code example for a specific case that is failing?

Comment: board_num I am using just to run anyone if-else condition. like if board_num = 2 first condition will satisfy. if board_num = 3 second condition and if board_num = 4 forth condition will satisfy.   I know it is quite messy can you please help how to make the correct loop.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the reshape operation? Your code will fail with each of the `b` and `n` values implied by your example - the reshape operations you're attempting always result in an error.

Comment: In "self.b" I am storing a list of elements ('R' and 'B'). In "numpy.arange(16).reshape((4,4))" I convert the list into 4X4 array. In this line  "self.b=numpy.array(self.b)" I updated self.b. Here "numpy.random.shuffle(self.b)" I am shuffling the array elements. Here "self.b=self.b.reshape(4,4)" here again reshape the array.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to make a board game where the board size is not fixed it can be of 2X2, 3X3 and 4X4 2-D array. So for that, I want to make a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit at what you're trying to accomplish, but here is how I might implement it:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:06) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> n = 4
>>> board = numpy.array(['R', 'B'])
>>> board = numpy.resize(board, (n, n))
>>> board
array([['R', 'B', 'R', 'B'],
       ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B'],
       ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B'],
       ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B']], dtype='<U1')
```

Or with the shuffle step:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> board = numpy.array(['R', 'B'])
>>> board = numpy.resize(board, n*n)
>>> board
array(['R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R',
       'B', 'R', 'B'], dtype='<U1')
>>> numpy.random.shuffle(board)
>>> board
array(['R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B',
       'B', 'R', 'B'], dtype='<U1')
>>> board = numpy.resize(board, (n, n))
>>> board
array([['R', 'B', 'R', 'R'],
       ['B', 'R', 'R', 'B'],
       ['R', 'R', 'B', 'B'],
       ['B', 'B', 'R', 'B']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Jay thank you so much for the solution. This is exactly what I was trying. I really appreciated. Thanks a lot.